# Transaction submits but is not valid when processed

Tags: erc-20, nodes, web3.py

I'm running two scripts that try to solve the same proof of work problem.

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from hexbytes import HexBytes

import numpy as np
import os
import time

INFURA_ROPSTEN_URL = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<api_key>"

# metamask account information
PUBLIC_KEY = "0x3FaD9AccC3A39aDbd9887E82F94602cEA6c7F86f"
PRIVATE_KEY = "<private_key>"

UNITS_ADDRESS = "0x8C4D48B42cdff260F14BBaD4E10d4144F1898bD4"
# from truffle build. For ABI
JSON_PATH = "../truffle/build/contracts/Units.json"



import logging
extra = {'miner_public_key': PUBLIC_KEY}
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
syslog = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(miner_public_key)s : %(message)s')
syslog.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(syslog)

logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def set_up_web3():
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(INFURA_ROPSTEN_URL))
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = PUBLIC_KEY
    return web3

def get_units_contract_object():
    with open(JSON_PATH, 'r') as json_file:
        abi = json.load(json_file)['abi']
    return web3.eth.contract(address=UNITS_ADDRESS,abi=abi)

def solve(web3, units):
    nonce = np.random.randint(0,1e10)
    while True:
        challenge_number_hex = HexBytes(units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()).hex()
        my_digest_hex = web3.solidityKeccak(
                            ['bytes32','address','uint256'],
                            [challenge_number_hex, PUBLIC_KEY, nonce]).hex()
        my_digest_number = int(my_digest_hex,0)
        target = units.functions.getMiningTarget().call()
        if my_digest_number < target:
            return (nonce, my_digest_hex, int(challenge_number_hex,0))
        else:
            nonce += 1

def build_transaction(units, nonce, digest_hex, txn_count):
    return units.functions.mint(
                    nonce,
                    digest_hex
            ).buildTransaction({
                "nonce" : txn_count,
        })

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    web3 = set_up_web3()

    txn_count = 11000 # web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY)
    units = get_units_contract_object()

    _cycle_goal = 20
    _prev_finish = time.time()
    _wait_time = 0
    while True:
        target = units.functions.getMiningTarget().call()
        nonce, digest_hex, challenge_number = solve(web3, units)

        mint_txn = build_transaction(units, nonce,digest_hex, txn_count)
        signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(mint_txn, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
        txn_address = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
        txn_count += 1

        log = f"Solution found! nonce={nonce}, digest_hex={digest_hex}, challenge_number={challenge_number}, txn_address={signed_txn}"
        logger.info(log)

        _finished = time.time()
        _elapsed = _finished - _prev_finish
        _additional_wait = _cycle_goal - _elapsed
        _wait_time += _additional_wait
        log = f"Waiting {_wait_time}"
        logger.info(log)
        _prev_finish = _finished
        time.sleep(_wait_time)
```

The transactions send just fine and looks like it should be successful, yet on [etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8c4d48b42cdff260f14bbad4e10d4144f1898bd4) sometimes the transaction fails.

I'm pretty sure that the reason why it fails is that I have portion in my contract that updates the challengeNumber whenever it gets solved. The line in the solidity contract is

```
challengeNumber = blockhash(block.number - 1);
```

So what must be happening is before this line learns from Infura that this should be returning something different

```
challenge_number_hex = HexBytes(units.functions.getChallengeNumber().call()).hex()
```

It's solving for the wrong solution.

I'm querying for this new value every time it tries to find a solution though so I'm not sure how I could get the new value any better.

---

Edit: Contract Code!

```
function mint(uint256 nonce, bytes32 challenge_digest) public returns (bool success) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challengeNumber, msg.sender, nonce));

        // Prove digest
        if (digest != challenge_digest) revert();
        // Check if digest is invalid
        if(uint256(digest) > miningTarget) revert();

        // Check uniqueness of answer
        bytes32 solution = solutionForChallenge[challengeNumber];
        if(solution != 0x0) revert();
        // Store answer
        solutionForChallenge[challengeNumber] = digest;

        // Reward
        uint reward_amount = getMiningReward();
        _mint(msg.sender, reward_amount);

        // Store reward details
        lastRewardTo = msg.sender;
        lastRewardAmount = reward_amount;
        lastRewardEthBlockNumber = block.number;

        // Intialize next epoch
        _startNewMiningEpoch();

        return true;
    }

    function _startNewMiningEpoch() internal {
        // Update Era
        if (rewardEra <= lastBonusEra) {
            // Determine current era
            if (totalSupply() >= maxSupplyForBonusEra[rewardEra]) {
                rewardEra = rewardEra + 1;
            }

            // Assign corresponding era rate
            if (rewardEra <= lastBonusEra) {
                currentMonthlyRate = bonusEraMonthlyRate[rewardEra];
            } else {
                currentMonthlyRate = standardEraMonthlyRate;
            }
        }

        // New epoch
        epochCount = epochCount.add(1);

        // Check Difficulty
        if (epochCount % _BLOCKS_PER_READJUSTMENT == 0) {
            _reAdjustDifficulty();
        }

        // Prevents pre-mine
        challengeNumber = blockhash(block.number - 1);
    }

    function _reAdjustDifficulty() internal {
        // calculate target time (measured in ethereum blocks)
        uint blocks_per_readjustment = _BLOCKS_PER_READJUSTMENT;
        uint targetEthBlocksPerDiffPeriod = blocks_per_readjustment.mul(2); // * 2 => 1/2 speed as ethereum

        // calculate how long it took
        uint ethBlocksSinceLastDifficultyPeriod = block.number - latestDifficultyPeriodStarted;
        // check mint rate
        if (ethBlocksSinceLastDifficultyPeriod < targetEthBlocksPerDiffPeriod) { // fewer blocks than expected ==> too easy
            uint excess_block_pct = (targetEthBlocksPerDiffPeriod.mul(100)).div(ethBlocksSinceLastDifficultyPeriod);
            uint excess_block_pct_extra = excess_block_pct.sub(100).limitLessThan(1000); // "xx% over" evaluates to "xx"

            miningTarget = miningTarget.sub(miningTarget.div(2000).mul(excess_block_pct_extra));
        } else { // more blocks than expected ==> too hard
            uint shortage_block_pct = ethBlocksSinceLastDifficultyPeriod.mul(100).div(targetEthBlocksPerDiffPeriod);
            uint shortage_block_pct_extra = shortage_block_pct.sub(100).limitLessThan(1000);

            miningTarget = miningTarget.add(miningTarget.div(2000).mul(shortage_block_pct_extra));
        }

        latestDifficultyPeriodStarted = block.number;

        if(miningTarget < _MINIMUM_TARGET) {
            miningTarget = _MINIMUM_TARGET;
        }

        if(miningTarget < _MAXIMUM_TARGET) {
            miningTarget = _MAXIMUM_TARGET;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the contract code? Otherwise we'll be guessing. From etherscan there are two type of failures "out of gas" (83k gas instead 90k in the successful ones) and hitting revert (23k).

Comment: @Ismael Added the relevant contract lines!

Comment: The failures at 23k seem to be at the very beginning of `mint` likely the revert when testing for `miningTarget` or `challenge_digest`. The failures at 83k are more intriguing. They should be close the the end of the function but there's no revert, require or assert there. Perhaps some problem with SafeMath or in the _mint call. But it should be something to debug to be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by 23k and 83k? Is that something on etherscan?

Comment: In my first comment I mention that there two types of failures: one costs 83k gas and the other costs 23k gas.